# Get back to File object from a string

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I have a string representing a File and want to get it back to its File form.

I get the string this way:

```
 var image = event.dataTransfer.files[0];//image coming from a form
 var fileAsString;
 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onload = (function(theFile){
        return function(e){
                fileAsString = e.target.result,
        }
    })(image);

 fileReader.readAsText(image);
```

How can I get back the var fileAsString to a File object. Something like:

```
var imageFileAgain = new File(fileAsString).
```